# Trying to run a .sql file in wamp using the SOURCE command, but I get the error message 'Unknown database'. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have written my SQL code in a file using notepad with a .sql extension, and I'm trying to run said file from a MySQL v5.7.26 console using wamp server with the help of the SOURCE command. However, the file won't run and instead I get an error message saying 'Unknown database'.

Since my aforementioned .sql file is in a folder on my desktop, I passed the absolute path of the file in the SOURCE command.

I've also tried to create a new database, and then running the file.

Then I tried to run the file by dropping the database then creating a new one from scratch as shown from the snippet below. That's where my file starts from.

Both methods yield the same aforementioned error.

This is my SOURCE command:

```
mysql> SOURCE C:\Users\useme\Desktop\Harsh\new_ig_clone.sql;
```

This is how my code in the file starts from.

```
DROP DATABASE ig_clone;

CREATE DATABASE ig_clone;

USE ig_clone;
```

The following is the error I get after I use that command:-

['unknown database' error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNwcQ.png)

Please help me solve this issue, and explain where am I going wrong. Thank you.

[First page of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zruC.png)

Comment: *"Please help me solve this issue, and explain where am I going wrong."* We can't we need to see the `new_ig_clone.sql` file content..

Comment: That file contains a large amount of data, and i found it impractical to post the whole thing here. Hence I just posted the first three lines of the code. Rest is all tables and data.

Comment: then I'm afraid you'll have to solve it yourself as you can't expected us to guess/gamble whats in the file..

Comment: maybe a hint search in the .sql file on `USE <database>` structures or query parts where database names are in the statements like `CREATE TABLE database_name.table_name`/ `INSERT INTO database_name.table_name` /  `UPDATE database_name.table_name`..  Thats about the only suggestion i can give you..

Comment: i've added a snippet of the code. As you can see, the database name is not mentioned anywhere else in the rest of the code.

Comment: Well after a recheck of the error message it says `unknown command \U ...`   Not sure what it means -> https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysql.cc#L2431  seams that `find_command()` has failed..

Comment: Well `SOURCE` usage is tricky as it is a client extension to run a file in batch mode also the source code mentions something about a ["real" binary mode](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysql.cc#L2279) in the `find_command()` function..  Why not simply execute `mysql db_name < new_ig_clone.sql`   also explained in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) and see if that works..

Comment: i tried executing it directly but as i mentioned earlier before, the data im working with - or rather the data i want to work with - is considerably large that i can't simply execute it. so i thought of running it using a file.

Answer (score 0):

use the command:

```
SOURCE "filename";
```